# infinite loop detected, partial ../foo.mustache was previously loaded

Tags: java, templates, mustache, handlebars.java

Hi I have two handlebars templates which is as below.

**foo.mustache**

```
{{#if hasProperties}}
    {{>bar}}
{{/if}}{{^hasProperties}}{{propsName}}{{/hasProperties}}
```

**bar.mustache**

```
{{#propertyObject}}{{>foo}}{{/propertyObject}}
```

When I compile this and run, I get the following error.

> infinite loop detected, partial '/templates/foo.mustache' was
>   previously loaded

What is the proper way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution for this issue. It's not something related to the template itself. The `mustache` files were in correct order but there is a `property` in the mustache java implementation where `default` value is set to `false`.

`public void setInfiniteLoops(boolean infiniteLoops)` [link](http://javadox.com/com.github.jknack/handlebars/1.3.1/com/github/jknack/handlebars/Handlebars.html#infiniteLoops())

this method will actually set to accept infinite loops which will be needed if you are running a recursive call inside the `mustache` template itself.

I hope this will help anyone looking to solve a similar kind of error.